# MS Access: Filter combobox entries by value from parent form

Tags: forms, ms-access, nested-forms, subform

I want to create a subform in Microsoft Access where a dropdown contains values filtered by a value from the parent form. The data model looks like this:

[image: Data Model]

A facility can have multiple buildings containing multiple machines. Service teams of a facility look after this machines. The desired form looks like this:

[image]

My question is how to filter the combobox shown in the above screenshot so it only shows service teams belonging to the same facility as the machine they are going to be assigned to?
I want to do this - if possible - without any VBA coding, just using the frontend editor tools built in access.

Comment: Use "SELECT TeamID , TeamName FROM ServiceTeams WHERE FacilityID=Forms!Facilities!FacilityID" as the row source of ServiceTeam combo in the Machines form. And also set the column count=2 and column widths=0;3 .

Comment: EDIT: Typos in my code. Your solution works. thanks for the help.